# Min value in a 1 D array

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a 1D array in Matlab and calling another function to do it. However, I am getting an error when I try to find out the minimum element and its position within the array. I want to find out the minimum value in `maxSS` and then find its index position and use that to find the corresponding angle. Here's my code:

```
angle = linspace(0,pi/2,1000);

for i = 1:length(angle)
    [maxSS] = GetMaxShearStress(strainMatrix, complianceMatrix, angle(i));
    M = min(maxSS);
    [M,I] = min(maxSS);
    minimum_angle = angle();
end

disp(' The fibre angle that minimises the shear stress is 'num2str(minimum_angle) 'radians');
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `min`?

Comment: `I` gives you the index of where the minimum angle occurred.... did you even read the documentation for `min`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html

Comment: What does `GetMaxSheerStress` return? A vector or a single value?

Comment: No one said you were. Why doesn't `min` work? What outputs do you get when using it?

Comment: What is the error and at which line does it occur? What are you trying to do with `minimum_angle = angle();`? Are you sure there should be empty parenthesis after `angle`? Or is it supposed to be `angle(I)`?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
    [M,I] = min(maxSS(:))
```